# How do you use the predictive distribution with noise in Bayesian Optimization?

Tags: gaussian-process, noise, bayesian-optimization

I have been reading a paper on Bayesian Optimization, and I was reading the section on adding Gaussian noise to your Gaussian process. The article is:

- Brochu, Cora and de Freitas (2010). A Tutorial on Bayesian Optimization of Expensive Cost Functions, with Application to Active User Modeling and Hierarchical
  Reinforcement Learning. ([pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.2599.pdf), specifically: pages 18-19)

The article explains that noise can be modeled with a normal distribution such as $y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i,$ where noise is $\epsilon \sim N (0, \sigma^2).$  Then when calculating the prediction the functions, include the distributions instead of scalars, so how do I input that into the acquisition function (such as the probability of improvement function)?

The functions are on the bottom of page 18 of the link.  The mean and variance functions.